# How plugin works?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do plugin systems work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806361/how-do-plugin-systems-work)

I could not find any article clearing what happens when a plugin is installed.
AS exe of the program say browser is readonly how changes can be made to it.?
How it gets the address of the function of  plugin  and loads into process memory?

Comment: What plugin you are talking about ?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: [Your comment is not welcome here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76195/how-to-deal-with-have-you-tried-google-comments)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are right, sorry for that. It's just it really shows a lot of quality information, and it clearly states that OP didn't even try.

Answer (score 0):

The main application is designed in a special way to provide a service for plug-in registering, and usually they also have a special protocol to communicate with the plug-in.

The application developer usually provides an API that plug-in developers can use. It's not much different from creating an application that uses an API of some web service.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is generally a dynamically loaded library (DLL under Windows, so under Linux), that gets loaded by the browser. Then, the browser looks for a specific symbol through which the functionality (API) of the plugin is exported.